# ul/li items not displaying correctly in a div

Tags: html, css

i have this code css code, i am trying to display the HTML (below) inside another div

```
/* EXTENDED FEATURES */
.four-col {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
.four-col h3{
    font-size:17px;
}
.four-col ul{
    margin:10px 0 10px -10px;
    list-style-image:url(../images/icon_tick1.png);
}
.four-col li{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1px 0;

<div class="four-col">
                            <h3>Account Features</h3>
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Unlimited MySQL 5 Databases</li>
                                 <li>Unlimited FTP Accounts</li>
                                 <li>SSH</li>
                                 <li>PHP 5.3, 5.4 & 5.5</li>
                                 <li>PEAR</li>
                                 <li>Zend Guard Loader</li>
                                 <li>Ioncube Loader</li>
                                 <li>Ruby On Rails</li>
                                 <li>Perl</li>
                                 <li>CGI</li>
                                 <li>Python</li>
                                 <li>Server Side Includes</li>
                                 <li>cURL</li>
                                 <li>GD2</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- four-col -->
                        <div class="four-col">
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Cron Jobs</li>
                                 <li>ImageMagick</li>
                                 <li>Zend Framework</li>
                                 <li>FFmpeg</li>
                                 <li>Flv2tools</li>
                                 <li>LAME MP3 Encoder</li>
                                 <li>Libogg &#38; Libvorbis</li>
                                 <li>Mplayer &#38; Mencoder</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h3>Control Panel Features</h3>
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Latest cPanel</li>
                                 <li>Softaculous</li>
                                 <li>RVSiteBuilder Pro</li>
                                 <li>R1Soft CDP Backups</li>
                                 <li>CloudFlare CDN Plugin</li>
                                 <li>Custom Error Pages</li>
                        </div><!-- four-col -->
                        <div class="four-col">
                            <ul>
                                 <li>IP Deny Manager</li>
                                 <li>Hotlink Protection</li>
                                 <li>Password Protect Directories</li>
                                 <li>Redirects</li>
                                 <li>phpMyAdmin</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h3>Email Features</h3>
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Unlimited POP3 Accounts</li>
                                 <li>Unlimited Auto Responders</li>
                                 <li>Unlimited E-Mail Forwarders</li>
                                 <li>Web Mail</li>
                                 <li>Mailing Lists</li>
                                 <li>Spam Assassin</li>
                                 <li>SMTP</li>
                                 <li>IMAP</li>
                                 <li>SPF &#38; DomainKeys</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- four-col -->
                        <div class="four-col">
                            <h3>Domains &#38; IP Addresses</h3>
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Unlimited Sub Domains</li>
                                 <li>Unlimited Add-On Domains</li>
                                 <li>Unlimited Parked Domains</li>
                                 <li>Dedicated IP ($1.95/mo)</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h3>Web Reports &#38; Statistics</h3>
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Awstats</li>
                                 <li>Webalizer</li>
                                 <li>Logaholic</li>
                                 <li>Access Logs</li>
                                 <li>Error Logs</li>
                                 <li>Bandwidth Usage</li>
                                 <li>Diskspace Usage</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- four-col -->
```

but the outside div is not displaying the right height - this is visible as it has a border on it

here is a fiddle with the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/LwPMN/

i want the `four-col` div to display inside the `web_hosting_extended_features` div

Comment: Don think this will fix the issue, but you are missing `</ul>` for the Control Panel Features list. As for your issue, try using a a clearfix css solve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden` to the `.tabcontent` element:

```
.tabcontent {
    /* other CSS untouched */        
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LwPMN/1/).

Or you can add a `clear: both` element before the closing tag of the same element (in this case I used a `br`, but any element will do):

```
<div class="tabcontent" id="web_hosting_extended_features-1">
    <!-- all content removed -->
        <br />
    <!-- four-col -->
</div>

br {
    clear: both;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LwPMN/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Use another div with `clear:both;` after all four-col divs. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwPMN/2/). It is needed because your four-cols have `float:left;`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS code to your styles

```
#web_hosting_extended_features-1{
```

overflow: hidden;
}

Also look into the CSS Clearfix for future reference http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the clearfix css fix

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1; /* IE < 8 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LwPMN/6/

Answer (score 0):

add "overflow: hidden;" to one of those CSS rules.

```
div#web_hosting_extended_features-1{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabcontent{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using floats. You either need to clear your floats, or go with the "new way", which would be to set `overflow: auto;` to your outter div (`.tabcontent`)